# Android USB Accessory can not receive data, InputStream.read never returns

Tags: usb, host, accessory

I have two Android phones, both Android 6.0. I want them to communicate with each other via USB. I have an OTG USB cable that will plug one phone into the other.
One is usb host, the other is accessory.

My code is based on following tutorials:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

Now

1. *The host and accessory can connect*
   According to this project:https://github.com/quandoo/android2android-accessory
   Host sends a control message :
   `private void initStringControlTransfer(final UsbDeviceConnection deviceConnection,
                                          final int index,
                                          final String string) {
       deviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 52, 0, index, string.getBytes(), string.length(), USB_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
    }
    initStringControlTransfer(connection, 0, "UsbTest Example"); // MANUFACTURER
    initStringControlTransfer(connection, 1, "UsbTest"); // MODEL
    initStringControlTransfer(connection, 2, "Test Usb Host and Accessory"); // DESCRIPTION
    initStringControlTransfer(connection, 3, "0.1"); // VERSION
    initStringControlTransfer(connection, 4, ""); // URI
    initStringControlTransfer(connection, 5, "42"); // SERIAL
    connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 53, 0, 0, new byte[]{}, 0, USB_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);`
2. *The host can receive data from accessory use UsbRequest*
   ***Host Code***:
   `UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
    request.initialize(mConnection, mEndIn); 
    boolean ret = request.queue(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE_IN_BYTES);
    if (ret) {
       if (mConnection.requestWait() == request) {
           // Succeed
       }
    }`
   ***Accessory Code***:
   `try {
       mOutStream.write(sendBuff);
       mOutStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }`
3. *the accessory can not receive data*
   ***Host Code***
   `int len = mInStream.read(msg); // block here, read never return
   if (len > 0) {
       // succeed
   }`
   ***Accessory Code***:
   `UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
    request.initialize(mConnection, mEndOut);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(text.getBytes());
    boolean ret = request.queue(buffer, text.getBytes().length);
    if (ret) {
       // request.queue succeed
    }
    // if I use bulkTransfer, it always return a negative value
    //int len = mConnection.bulkTransfer(mEndOut, text.getBytes(), text.getBytes().length, USB_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
    //if (len < 0) {
    //    // always run here
    //} else {
    //

    //}`

Does anybody know about this?

Comment: Hello do you found any solution about this problem ?

Comment: Not yet.  I am busy with another project.